# matching the columns in a source file with sink table columns to make sure they match using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have an Azure Data factory trigger that is fired off when a file is placed in blob storage, this trigger will start pipeline execution and pass the file name to the data flow activity. I would like to make sure that all the column names from the header row in the file are in the sink table.  There is an identity column in the sink table that should not be in the comparison. Not sure how to tackle this task, I've read about the 'derived column' activity, is that the route I should take?

Comment: Are you looking for validating schema or column names against an existing table at sink ? or do you just want to remove "identity" column and write rest columns into sink ?

Comment: just need to verify the column names and that they are all accounted for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select or filter which columns reside in sink dataset or table by using "**Field mapping**". You can optionally use "`derived columns`" transformation, however in the "`sink transformation`" you will have this by default and is set to "**Auto mapping**". Here you can add or remove which columns are written to sink.

In the below example the column "`id`" can be assumed as similar to "`Identity`" column in your table. Assuming all the files have same columns:

[image]

[image]

Once you have modified as per your need, you can confirm the same from the "`inspect`" tab before run.

[image]

Comment: the columns may vary from file to file

Comment: i made a comment to diego about how the input behaves. the sql table is premade by an admin. and the csv file is also premade and given to the user. it will match BUT incase the user accidentally messes up a name of a column or deletes one all together or adds one. i need to catch that. the csv files may have  a different amount of columns and names but they mapped to a made sql table based on the file name, in the sink i parse the name to find the table in sql, hope this helps

Comment: i can have a "master template" for each customer with their version of the template type in blob storage, can i reference that and compare with the uploaded file and see if they match ?

Answer (score 0):

**Strategy:**

Use two ADF pipelines, one to get a list of all files and another one to process each file copying its content to a specific SQL table.

**Setup:**

I’ve created 4 CSV files, following the pattern you need: “[CustomerID]*[TableName]*[FileID].csv” and 4 SQL tables, one for each type of file.

- A_inventory_0001.csv: inventory records for customer A, to be
  inserted into the SQL table “A_Inventory”.
- A_sales_0003.csv: sales
  records for customer A, to be inserted into the SQL table “A_Sales”.
- B_inventory_0002.csv: inventory records for customer B, to be
  inserted into the SQL table “B_Inventory”.
- B_sales_0004.csv: sales
  records for customer B, to be inserted into the SQL table “B_Sales”

[image: strategy]

**Linked Services**

In Azure Data Factory, the following linked services were create using Key Vault (Key Vault is optional).

[image: linked services]

**Datasets**

The following datasets were created. Note we have created some parameters to allow the pipeline to specify the source file and the destination SQL table.

The dataset “AzureSQLTable” has a parameter to specify the name of the destination SQL table.

[image: dataset-AzureSQLTable]

The dataset “DelimitedTextFile” has a parameter to specify the name of the source CSV file.

[image: dataset-DelimitedTextFile]

The dataset “DelimitedTextFiles” has no parameter because it will be used to list all files from source folder.

[image: dataset-DelimitedTextFiles]

**Pipelines**

The first pipeline “Get Files” will get the list of CSV files from source folder (Get Metadata activity), and then, for each file, call the second pipeline passing the CSV file name as a parameter.

[image: pipeline-GetFiles1]

[image: pipeline-GetFiles2]

Inside the foreach loop, there is a call to the second pipeline “Process File” passing the file name as a parameter.

[image: pipeline-GetFiles3]

The second pipeline has a parameter “pFileName” to receive the name of the file to be processed and a variable to calculate the name of the destination table based on the file name.

[image: pipeline-ProcessFile1]

The first activity is to use a split in the file name to extract the parts we need to compose the destination table name.
In the expression bellow we are splitting the file name using the “__” separator and then using the first and second parts to compose the destination table name.
`@concat(string(split(pipeline().parameters.pFileName, '_')[0]),'_',string(split(pipeline().parameters.pFileName, '_')[10]))`

[image: pipeline-ProcessFile2]

The second activity will then copy the file from the source “pFileName” to the desnation table “vTableName” using dynamic mapping, ie not adding specific column names as this will be dynamic.

[image: pipeline-ProcessFileCopy]

The files I used in this example and the ADF code are available here:
https://github.com/diegoeick/stack-overflow/tree/main/69340699

I hope this will resolve your issue.

In case you still need to save the CustomerID and FileID in the database tables, you can use the dynamic mapping and use the available parameters (filename) and create a json with the dynamic mapping in the mapping tab of your copy activity. You can find more details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping#parameterize-mapping

Comment: there is one issue, this data flow has to process a file that may have one set of columns with certain names and then process another file that has a different set of columns with different names.

Comment: the name of the file will be used to find the table where it will be uploaded. for instance, customer A has an inventory csv file he needs to upload and the file name is "A_inventory_1234.csv"  well this name has the customer ID which is 'A' and type of file 'inventory' and the fileID '1234'. the table in sql will have a table named 'A_inventory' and the columns in that file has to match that table. Customer B wants to upload a csv file also but it maybe a different type of file with a different set of columns, the name would be the same format 'B_Sales_3215.csv'.

Comment: so i will need to compare the columns in 'B_Sales' to that file. hope this helps

Comment: Hi Edgar,
I believe now I understand your question with these additional details. I’ve just edited  my original answer adding some additional steps. If that resolves your question, please mark the answer as useful. Have fun ;)